# Setting two charsets? utf-8 and text/html

Tags: html

I'm new to learning HTML and learning about metadata in a webpage. It seems like people prefer you have  to set the character set to support utf-8 and people are also saying have charset="text/html" so browsers know what kind of information they are receiving. How can I set both since it seems like both use the same attribute?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542505/can-i-declare-two-different-charsets-on-one-html-page-using-a-meta-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text/html` is a media type, not a character set. The server can send a `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` header to identify the content as HTML encoded as UTF-8. When you’re using a `<meta>` tag, though, the content is already known to be HTML and the only thing that matters is the charset, so HTML5 introduced the option to write `<meta charset="utf-8">` as shorthand for `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`. (Older browsers also support this because people had a habit of forgetting quotes in the original.)

In short, if you’re using a `<meta>` tag, just write this:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and you’re done. The page is already HTML.